# understanding dual vectors and dual spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

please help me with number example to understand better  what is a  co-vector and what is a dual vector space,as i know it is related to fact,that it eats  vector,which means that it takes vector and calculates scalar,also as i know there should be used linear function,or functions which satisfies  following  relations

1.$f(v_1+v_2)=f(v_1)+f(v_2)$

2,$f(a*v)=a*f(v)$

so let take some vector ,let say

$V=v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4...v_n$ ok let take numbers $V=(3,4,5,6,7,8)$ and i want to calculate  it's  corresponding  co vector,how could i solve this problem,let take this  function

$f(x)=5*x$

because it is linear

$f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1)+f(x_2)$

2.$f(a*x)=a*f(x)$

how to apply it to vector and produce co vector?please help me

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50222/covectors-and-vectors

Comment: i  read  all this definition,but could not understand,that why i have posted  to make explanation easiest

Comment: could you give me example with  simply example?

Comment: i am going  to bad,and please  just   i need example without formal notations,it makes impossible for me to understand  topic,so please  with real numbers

Comment: Dear dato, Have you seen [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3755/221)? Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(x)=5x$ is not a covector for the space of vectors of the form $V=v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,\ldots,v_n$. (I'm assuming that $n>1$.) A covector must input a vector and output a scalar. Your function $f$ inputs a vector and outputs another vector.

Here's a better example. Let $g(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6)=v_1-v_3+v_4-v_6$. Then $g$ is a covector on $\mathbb R^6$, and given your vector $V=(3,4,5,6,7,8)$, we have $g(V)=3-5+6-8=-4$.

About a couple of your sub-questions:

> I want to calculate its corresponding covector

Given a vector $V$, there is generally no covector corresponding to $V$. (There will be such a correspondence if you have an inner product, but don't worry about that until you get to it.)

> how to apply it to vector and produce a covector?

I think you mean how to apply a covector to a vector and produce a *scalar*.